# can you begin a mysql statement with "IF"?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, conditional-statements

I am trying to implement "IF record EXISTS THEN UPDATE ELSE INSERT" in mysql.  Specifically, I have to figure out how to do that with Doctrine ORM.

One solution using native MySql is to use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".  This is unfortunately not supported in Doctrine.

Another semi solution is to use "REPLACE INTO" syntax.  Doctrine supports this, however REPLACE doesn't UPDATE records, instead it drops the record and creates a new one (with a new auto increment id.)  Because of this, it's a bad solution if you depend on auto-increment ids as I do.

The table I'm trying to operate on is INNODB, so I have looked into transactions, but I don't fully understand if the same rules apply inside of transactions as apply outside of them.

Can I say "IF(INSERT IGNORE INTO table `critical_id` = $id) THEN exit ELSE (UPDATE table SET `field` = 'new_value')" inside of a transaction?

If I can't say something like that, is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either find a way to make "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" work, or switch to using two statements: first SELECT to find any existing rows, then UPDATE or INSERT as necessary.

That's pretty much your only option, short of building a stored proc that does the above work for you.

Comment: I found a way to use "ON DUPLICATE KEY" and I think it was the best solution, so I will accept this answer, but I am still trying to figure out if there's a transactional solution with no mysql specific terminology.  fwiw, the question posed in the title was never answered.  I think the answer is that you can't begin a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE statement with IF.  I have heard of a property called Recordcount that exists in other dbms'.  I have been looking for a mysql equivalent - an "inner-transactional counter" - to tell me if any records were modified.  still looking.

Answer (score 1):

"Insert or update" is called "Upsert". If you google "upsert mysql" you will find that there are only few solutions.

1. 2-step, Insert, then Update and variations
2. "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"
3. REPLACE

And maybe few more, but most of those are variations.

Using transactions your SQL would look like this:

```
    UPDATE xxx SET (x1, x2) = (y1, y2) WHERE id = myid;
    IF found THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO xxx (x1, x2) VALUES (y1, y2);
        RETURN;
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    --##Do nothing, or you can put this whole sql code
    --##in a LOOP and it will loop over and try update again
    END;
```

This code is stripped from one of my postgresql functions. I think InnoDB doesn't support this, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have already mentioned INSERT IGNORE INTO.  Is this not meeting your needs?

http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html

Comment: I am looking to UPDATE the record if it already exists.  INSERT IGNORE will just skip the whole thing, unless I am mistaken.